# Paging inside a content

Tags: php, pagination

Consider an article inside a div that has many `<p>` tag. Is there any serverside way -( php, mysql) to paging `<p>` inside div?

```
<div id="page">
  <p>lipsum</p>
  <p>lipsum</p>
  <p>lipsum</p>
  <p>lipsum</p>
</div>
```

EDIT:
I can search in google for php pagination and I have read some o them. I want to paginate specific tags inside one filed not fetch specific rows. There isnt any get query. This is only a dynamic article that fetched from a field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think pagination can be done where ever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to paginate content inside single article and article is stored in single row in database. You will have to do it in php.

1. retrieve content of article from database
2. explode content into parts, I do this on one of my sites by inserting

   ```
   <!-- BRAKE -->
   ```

   inside content where I want brake to happed when writing article before storing it in database
3. Make the usual pagination logic for displaying certain article part

Second step is trick, if you want to break it on p I suggest using some [DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to do it.